# Mapbox hover popup won't close

Tags: javascript, popup, hover, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I've adapted the Mapbox example for a [popup on hover](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/popup-on-hover/) using another example for a [popup on click](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/popup-on-click/), and everything is working great except that the popup won't close on "mouseleave". I must have done something wrong when I combined the two examples but I can't find the answer anywhere. Please help!

```js
<html>
  <body>
    <div id='map'></div>
    <script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFyeXNoYWZmZXIiLCJhIjoiY2poNnkwZ3pvMDI5ZzJ4cWUyY296NnNjdCJ9.PgJCuPhDYgm8oCmsZlAeQA'; // replace this with your access token
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/maryshaffer/cjh6yf7c30apg2sotfzmyf2je', // replace this with your style URL
    });
      
    // code from the next step will go here
  map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
 
  map.on('mouseenter', 'pilgrimage-sites-markers', function(e) {
        // Change the cursor style as a UI indicator.
        map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
    });
  
  map.on('mouseenter', 'pilgrimage-sites-markers', function(e) {
  var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
    layers: ['pilgrimage-sites-markers'] // replace this with the name of the layer
  });

  if (!features.length) {
    return;
  }

  var feature = features[0];

  var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
    closeOnClick: false,
    offset: [0, -15] })
    .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
    .setHTML('<h3>' + feature.properties.title + '</h3><p>' + feature.properties.description + '</p><h4><a href=\"' + feature.properties.link + '\">Learn More</a></h4>')
    .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
    .addTo(map);
});  
      
 map.on('mouseleave', 'pilgrimage-sites-markers', function() {
        map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
        popup.remove();
  });
      
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `popup` variable is declared locally inside the handler of the `map.on('mouseenter')` event.

And, accordingly, it is not defined inside the handler of the `map.on('mouseleave')` event.

So you need to move the declarations of the `popup` variable to the scope of both functions.

For example: https://jsfiddle.net/e5j10x1o/

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly and was exactly the answer I needed! I actually realized that I don't want the popup to disappear when you stop hovering over the point, because then people can't click on the "Learn More" link in the popup, but your answer was absolutely correct and will be helpful for me in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the JS Fiddle, this helped me understand how to open/close popups