# Mapbox Store Locator example: mouse exit for the popups?

Tags: mapbox

Followed the example at https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/building-a-store-locator/

Worked well.  However, the example popup stays in place on mouse exit until your mouseover another marker.  Trying to get the popup to disappear on mouseleave.

The popup code from the example is:

```
/* Create a Mapbox GL JS `Popup`.
**/
function createPopUp(currentFeature) {
    var popUps = document.getElementsByClassName('mapboxgl-popup');
    if (popUps[0]) popUps[0].remove(0);
    var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({closeOnClick: false})
        .setLngLat(currentFeature.geometry.coordinates)
        .setHTML('<h3>' + currentFeature.properties.address + '</h4>' +
        '<h4>' + currentFeature.properties.sites + '</h4>')
        .addTo(map);
}
```

I think the answer lies in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50397421/mapbox-hover-popup-wont-close) but I dont know how to "move the mouseover declaration" as suggested in the context of my code.

Thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific, what exactly code you want to improve and how you tried to do it? And finally what is really the question?

Comment: Will edit the psot.